# Apex @testSetup

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I have the below test but I can't figure out why the opportunity won't query. When I run this test class, the error I keep getting is "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" that happens at the Opportunity test method

Specific line:

```
opportunity o = [SELECT Name, id, StageName, LastApexUpdate__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name='Test Opp' LIMIT 1];
```

Entire test:

```
@isTest
public class testAutomationTrigger{

    @testSetup 
    static void setup() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;

        opportunity o = new Opportunity();
        o.name = 'Test Opp';
        o.Practice_Name__c = 'Test Practice';
        o.StageName = 'Demo Scheduled';
        o.CloseDate = date.today().addDays(10);
        o.AccountId = a.id;
        insert o;

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName='TestContact', 
                                  Email='testContact@test.com', 
                                  AccountId = a.Id, 
                                  LeadSource='Inbound Call');
        insert con;

        Case cs = new Case(AccountId = a.id,
                           ContactId = con.id,
                           Description = 'test',
                           Status = 'New',
                           Subject = 'testSubject');
        insert cs;

        Product2 product = new Product2(); 
        product.name = 'Test Product';
        insert product;

        zqu__QuoteAmendment__c qa = new zqu__QuoteAmendment__c();
        qa.name = 'AH Test Test';
        qa.zqu__Quote__c = q.id;
        insert qa;

        zqu__QuoteRatePlan__c qrp = new zqu__QuoteRatePlan__c();
        qrp.Name = 'Service Plan';
        qrp.zqu__QuoteAmendment__c = qa.id; 
        qrp.zqu__QuoteProductName__c = 'test';
        insert qrp;        

    }


    @isTest
    static void testReputation(){
        opportunity o = [SELECT Name, id, StageName, LastApexUpdate__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name='Test Opp' LIMIT 1];

        zqu__QuoteRatePlan__c qrp = [SELECT Id, zqu__QuoteProductName__c FROM zqu__QuoteRatePlan__c WHERE Name='Service Plan' LIMIT 1];
        qrp.zqu__QuoteProductName__c = 'Reputation Accelerator';

        Test.startTest();

        o.stageName = 'Closed Won';
        o.LastApexUpdate__c = DateTime.Now();
        update o;

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any triggers or workflows which might be changing the name? What API Version are you using? You could try `system.assert(false, [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity])` and see what the actual value is.

Comment: If you know that's the only opp created by testSetup (i.e. no opps created by triggers), then you don't really need to specify Name in your SOQL where clause, just do `SELECT Name, StageName, LastApexUpdate__c FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1`

Comment: In the `@testSetup`, on the line after you insert the opportunity, add `system.assert(o.Id != null);`. If you run the test and it fails with the following message `System.AssertException: Assertion Failed`, then that means your Opportunity is not being inserted. You will need to look through your debug logs to figure out why the Opp is not being inserted.